NOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/docs/swagger/routes', in vercel when i deploy nodejs project
my code and structure code
log vercel
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/docs/swagger/routes'
at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1508:26)
at getDocs (/var/task/backend/helper/generate.docs.js:14:13)
at generateDocs (/var/task/backend/helper/generate.docs.js:24:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/backend/index.js:28:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at exports.c (/opt/node-bridge/chunk-IGLN3GKU.js:1:1142)
at /opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-VJJG62X5.js:1:1445 {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/var/task/docs/swagger/routes'
}
how to solve this error? please help me
